# How to open contacts and show the picked contacts in a list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am trying to make a button to opens up my contacts and let me choose contacts I want to pick. Then, list the names and(maybe) their mobile numbers on a list. So far, I'm stuck on opening the contacts from my phone. Hope you can help me. Thanks! Here's my code:

```
public class RecipientsFragment extends Fragment {
public Button button;
static final int PICK_CONTACT=1;

public RecipientsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipients, container, false);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipients, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String cNumber = null;
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  getActivity().managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {


                    String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


                    String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,
                                null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                    }
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    System.out.println("number is:"+cNumber+" Name :"+name);

                }
            }
            break;
    }
}



}
```

Comment: Please check -> https://trinitytuts.com/get-contact-list-and-show-in-custom-listview-android/g2=5sMQchZjhxIkC7x3nyuihA&bvm=bv.134495766,d.c2I&cad=rja

Comment: Please check demo of ContactManager https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/ContactManager

Comment: Hello, @AndiGeeky. Thank you for noticing my post. It says that page 404 not found.

Comment: Hello, @ChiragSavsani. I will check this and let you know about it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// You need below permission to read contacts

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

// Declare this at Global variable

```
 static final int PICK_CONTACT=1;
```

// put this code in Click event

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

// put this code outSide the OnCreate()

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

 switch (reqCode) {
 case (PICK_CONTACT) :
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
String cNumber=null;
     Uri contactData = data.getData();
     Cursor c =  getActivity().managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {


         String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


         String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
          Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query( 
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                       null, null);
             phones.moveToFirst();
              cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));

           }
         String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
System.out.println("number is:"+cNumber+" Name :"+name);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "number is:"+cNumber+" Name :"+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
   }
   break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hello, @Rjz. Where do i put the codes of //code for show number? Thanks!

Comment: let me Update my answer

Comment: Sure, @Rjz. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, @Rjz. I'm afraid it's not. I'm having an error in these lines:

Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);  (managedQuery is in red)

Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(    (getContentResolver is in red)

cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));   (cNumber is in red)

 System.out.println("number is:"+cNumber+" Name :"+name);  (cNumber is in red)

Comment: now check my updated code.,.,.,. you will get number and name in LOGCAT...

Comment: Hello, @Rjz. Thank you for your time. I will try this code and let you know what the results are. I will also mark this one answered when it's working.

Comment: Hello, @Rjz. I'm sorry to say but it's not working. Whenever i click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, @Rjz. Whenever i press the button to open contacts. Nothing happens.

Comment: its purely worked with me. wait. i will make code for you.

Comment: Please see my updated code. In case you missed it, I have a button where it must open my contacts. And so far, it's not working. Thanks, @Rjz

Comment: reomve  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipients, container, false);

Comment: write "return view ;" only

Comment: When i remove it. There will be an error in the last "}" of  the onCreate and says "missing return statement"

Comment: I see, let me try.

Comment: Well, it worked now @Rjz. Thank you! I will mark your answer. Thanks!